# c++ vector to store binary file, memory problems

Tags: c++, memory, binary, heap-memory, stack-memory

I believe I am getting memory problems with due to the following code:

```
    const char *current = "myfile.txt"

    std::ifstream input( current, std::ios::binary );
    // copies all data into buffer
    std::vector<BYTE> buffer((
                              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)),
                             (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    std::string encodedData = base64_encode(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
    printf("%d - %s", encodedData.size(), encodedData.c_str());
```

I'm wondering, is it because the strings are being created on the stack instead of the heap? Is there any way to get the strings to be allocated to the heap?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "problems"?

Comment: Can you make sure that `encodedData.c_str()` is really NUL-terminated?

Comment: Is "myfile.txt" big, and you don't want your program to store multiple copies of it in memory? You have a stream ...

Comment: Remember, the `std::vector` may resize it's internal array as the file is read in.  This could lead to heap memory fragmentation.

Comment: In the days of tape reels, we were taught to process large files in pieces or chunks.  Read in a chunk of data from the file, process it, then output it.  You may not *need* to read the entire file into memory, then copy it to another string.  BTW, the operating system may only read chunks of the file into memory anyway.

Comment: Thus my request for clarification.  I would have posted an answer reading a buffer of size LCM(3, io-block) so the base64 is correct. There's never any good reason to have any more than that in memory at once.